# USB Modem Driver Problem Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: usb-modem, modem

I am using ZTE USB modem which comes with our local network operator Grameenphone (grameenphone.com). In Ubuntu 12.04 , I have been using this modem properly. But in Ubuntu 14.04, after installing the modem driver, the application named grameenphone internet ( application > grameenphone ) can not run. This is the driver link I am trying to install: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6f9YmB1zd0RWFdNdHV0UGpnWTQ/edit?pli=1

Trying to install with terminal:

[image]

Comment: Please provide the data from `lspci` and `lsusb` on your question so we can give you better and faster help.

Answer (score 0):

`gcc: command not found` a few lines up in your jpg image.

Check why the GNU C compiler isn't found (if you have it installed) and you might get at least a few steps further.